# Client side authentication and protected routes using cookies in react

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux, jwt, react-router-v4

I am currently using stateless JWT token for authentication in my app. In the client side I am running a React + Redux app which has protected routes. It is implemented using a HOC which checks if the jwt token exists and allows the route based on it.

I recently read that localstorage is not a good place for storing JWT tokens. Therefore I am switching to using jwt in cookies.

But the problem is how do I implement protected routes on the client side when using cookies. 
I am using react-router-dom in the react app for routing.

Comment: I would think you would use an api call using the cookie which would return user information for that user. A result of that call would be an updated redux store which in turn would 'protect' client routes.

Comment: I did consider this approach. but  every time you visit a protected route the HOC has to make a call to the api to check and there is a lag before the request resolves.  I don't want to show a loader before every page loads.

Comment: @uman you can do it only once when you app is mounted. For all the protected routes, I believe you are also validating the API calls on your backend, (e.g. when you mount your protected component, you call your API for authorized-only data for that screen), so whenever you get an `Unauthorized` response, you can always redirect the user to the right place or even clear the redux store all together during this redirect.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple, Just use an if else

App.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import "./App.css";
import Auth from "./Components/Pages/Auth/Auth";
import Logout from "./Components/Pages/Auth/Logout/Logout";
import { checkAuthStatus } from "./Components/store/actions";

function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.checkAuthStatus(); // checking authentication status of user on each reload
  }, []);

  // filtering routes based on the authentication state of user
  const getRoutes = () => {
    if (props.auth) {
      return <Switch>{/* ...authenticated routes */}</Switch>;
    } else {
      // unauthenticated routes
      return (
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
          <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
          <Redirect to="/auth" />
        </Switch>
      );
    }
  };
  console.log(props.error);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
          {props.loading ? <div>Authenticating...</div> : getRoutes()}
        </Suspense>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth:
      state.login.data.token !== undefined && state.login.data.token !== null,
    loading: state.login.loading,
    error: state.login.error,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    checkAuthStatus: () => dispatch(checkAuthStatus()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

#### actions.js

```
import { axiosInstance } from "../../Utility/axiosInstance";
import { getCookie } from "../../Utility/cookies";
import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";

export const loginStart = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.LOGIN_START,
  };
};
export const loginFailure = (error) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE,
    error,
  };
};
export const loginSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    data,
  };
};

export const checkAuthStatus = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loginStart());
    let token = getCookie("token");
    axiosInstance
      .post("/checkauthstatus", { id: token })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        let error = "something went wrong";
        if (err.response) {
          error = err.response.message;
        }
        dispatch(loginFailure(error));
      });
  };
};
```